# Can't set PropTypes correctly in React bouncing between several alternatives

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my component I've used the following to set up the props, knowing that it's going to be some kind of data structure (and I was suggested that there's nothing to gain of exact definition of the object's fields).

```
Compy.propTypes = {
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  permissions: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
  dismiss: PropTypes.func
};
```

From that, I got the error as follows.

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `permissions[0]` of type **`string`** supplied to `Compy`, expected **`object`**.

Based on that, I assumed that the data is a string and that my expectations were wrong (it's an object that is being served but maybe it gets serialized or something, I thought). So I change the type as shown below.

```
Compy.propTypes = {
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  permissions: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
  dismiss: PropTypes.func
};
```

To my surprise, that produced the following error message.

> > Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `permissions[0]` of type **`object`** supplied to `Compy`, expected **`string`**.

I understand the *expected XXX* part, since I can see that declaration in the code. What buffles me is that it seems like the complaint changes back, requesting precisely the thing I had previously. What's up with that?

Then I figured that maybe the message complains in regard to the fields inside the object, so I declared a shape according to [a blog](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) as shown below. That structure matches precisely what the object looks like (two strings and an array of strings).

```
Compy.propTypes = {
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  permissions: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string,
    code: PropTypes.string,
    items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)
  })),
  dismiss: PropTypes.func
};
```

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `permissions[0]` of type `string` supplied to `Compy`, expected `object`.

It looks like the computer tries to annoy me by being on the contrary to anything I type. Of course, it's obvious that's not the case. However, being fairly new to React, I can't make sense of it and I'm convinced that, since it's a quite weird behavior, someone will recognize it as something that I can try to debug. At this moment I'm stuck.

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `permissions[0]` of type `string` supplied to `InvoiceCreationModal`, expected `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your permissions array is made up of objects and strings.
you should be able to avoid the warning by simply declare the fields as of type `PropTypes.any`

```
Compy.propTypes = {
  isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  permissions: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any),
  dismiss: PropTypes.func
};
```

alternatively you can try specifying the allowed types for your array

```
Compy.propTypes = {
   isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
   permissions: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object])),
   dismiss: PropTypes.func
};
```

or make it more flexible and specify in which case it should trigger the warning

```
Compy.propTypes = {
       isOpen: PropTypes.bool,
       permissions: PropTypes.arrayOf(function(propValue, key, componentName, location, propFullName) {
       if (!/matchme/.test(propValue[key])) {
         return new Error(
           'Invalid prop `' + propFullName + '` supplied to' +
           ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
         );
       }
    }),
       dismiss: PropTypes.func
    };
```

link to [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Comment: Thank you and yes, I can confirm that *PropTypes.any* did remove the error message. Now, the permissions array is made up of objects. Period. Each object has three fields - two strings and an array. That array is a bunch of strings. The question is answered as such and I'll check it green in 2 minutes. However, I'd also like to +1 you if you'd suggest a syntax that reflects said structure (instead of shuffling it under the carpet by *any*). Also, I'd like to bounty anybody who can share some comprehension on why exactly this *it's not - it's too* kind of weirdness can arise.

Comment: to understand what is going on you should debug it  to check what's the array content at runtime, cause it seems it's made of different types, anyway i've added some alternatives